# Haskell equivalent to contains

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Basically i'm trying to scan a string for words that contain a character and count the number of words found that have that character. I'm just wondering if there is a way to check if a word contains a character.

The code so far is as follows:

```
let w = "Hello i'm kind of new to Haskell, but so far it's great!"
length $ filter (== 'n') w
```

This gets any occurrence on the letter n though and if there was 2 n's in one word it would count that as 2 and not 1, I basically want to check if the words contains the letter input and then get the length.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look on https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ for `elem` and then have a look for `words`.

Comment: @Marcin Ah - I've edited my comment to be clearer what I meant, sorry. Thanks for the clarification, bheklilr.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `elem`:

```
> 'n' `elem` w
True
```

For future reference in case you haven't seen it before, there is actually a search engine that will look up functions based on type for Haskell.  If I search for `Char -> String -> Bool` or `String -> Char -> Bool` on [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) then `elem` is the second result.  This can be a very powerful tool for discovering functions you didn't know existed.

---

Reading your question a bit closer and realizing exactly what you want to do, you can combine `words`, `elem`, and `filter` pretty easily to count the number of words in a string that contain a particular letter:

```
wordsWithLetter :: Char -> String -> Int
wordsWithLetter c w
    = length
    $ filter (c `elem`)
    $ words w
```

Here `` filter (c `elem`) `` will remove all words that don't contain `c` so counting the remaining words using `length` tells you how many words contained that letter.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did not know about hoogle. Also it was probably my poorly worded question but I wanted the code to count the occurrences not return true or false.  Can this be used as a filter? So it will look for all words that have an element of 'n' and count that

Comment: @Jordan If you want to count the occurrences then `length $ filter (== 'n') w` would work just fine.  It would be how I would solve the problem.  However, if you wanted to count the occurrences of all characters in a string you would be better off using `Data.Map` and building a value of type `Map Char Int` as you iterate over your string.  That's a bit more complicated so if that's what you want to do I'd recommend asking a separate question.

Comment: @Jordan See my edits after I read your question a bit closer with the context of your comment.

Comment: `length . filter id . map f == length . filter f`. `filter id` looks suspicious.

Comment: @AndrewC don't I have that? Maybe the latter dot is ambiguous. Or should one use `≅` for `≡` for this kind of equivalences?

Comment: @OlegGrenrus Oh sorry, I read your comment on my phone and the distinction in the code highlighting for the latter dot escaped me.